# OrangePi Zero 3 once you have installed and booted a OS from micro SD card you can't eventually boot any different OS

Tags: linux, boot, arm

As I got my OrangePi Zero 3 device I successfully loaded Ubuntu22 image on an microSD and booted it nicely.

I eventually came across with the problem of screen borders being cut and in order to understand whether or not that was due to the Linux OS or to the device's HW itself, I decided to test a different OS.

I then tried Armbian, Debian and Arch but none of those could boot (the red led did not blink at all) having tested also different good micro SD cards.

I then re-flashed the original Ubuntu 22 image that worked at the first attempt and again it did happily boot without any issue.

It seems to me that once the OrangePi Zero 3 device has been initialized with a OS then it remains stuck to that OS unless the device is reset to initial factory state somehow. Yet I could not find any info regarding this anywhere.

Any idea on this issue?

Comment: Have you followed all steps at https://www.instructables.com/Orange-Pi-Zero-Setup-Getting-Started-With-Orange-P/ ? The OrangePi needs an OS particularly for that hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Eventually I understood that the problem was in all the public linux images shown at the orangepi site but Ubuntu and Debian that actually work fine. I  triesd Debian this morning and it works nicely and appears better than Ubuntu since with Ubuntu the screen is cropped a bit on the borders, with Debian the scree is perfet!

Comment: Just to clear this issue, the problem actually is in the Linux images supplied by orangepi.org site whereas only Ubuntu and Debian do work with orangepi zero 3 . Moreover I noticed that with Debian the cropping of the screen on the borders does not occur at all being the borders perfect with a resolution automatically set at that of the monitor in use (1366x768 in my case).

Comment: I have asked why the answer was turned into a comment: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15094/answer-by-op-was-converted-to-a-comment-interested-in-the-logic-behind-that?cb=1

Comment: @music2myear +1 (in meta)

Comment: @music2myear +1 from me too. we could consider submit as answer again?

Comment: Because a Mod deleted, community members cannot vote to undelete. OP to re-post, or Mod could undelete.